# I'm currently facing an issue with IronSource integration in my app

Tags: unity-game-engine, integration, mobile-ad-mediation, unityads, ironsource

I'm currently facing an issue with IronSource integration in my app. Both the rewarded videos and banners from Unity Ads, which are integrated through IronSource mediation, are not working properly. I keep encountering the 'Empty waterfall' error. Specifically, the rewarded videos show the following log message: `'2023/06/03 15:05:43.700 11015 11039 Info ironSourceSDK API:` isRewardedVideoAvailable():false', and the banners show these log messages: `'2023/06/03 15:34:19.032 12497 12497 Info ironSourceSDK CALLBACK: k 14.run - onBannerAdLoadFailed() error = Empty waterfall' and '2023/06/03 15:34:19.032 12497 12497 Info ironSourceSDK CALLBACK: k 15.run - onAdLoadFailed() error = Empty waterfall'.`

https://imgur.com/a/W1ZC1z0

I've tried troubleshooting on my own, but I haven't been able to find a solution. I have also tested the device in the IronSource website, and I encountered the same error. According to my setup, the Unity Ads should appear, but they are not.
I'm wondering if anyone has encountered a similar issue with IronSource integration and knows how to resolve it. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I think the best course of action here would be to contact their support. Are you seeing any other errors? Do you load ads successfully (even when using test campaigns)?

Comment: @tomerpacific No, I don't see any Unity ads showing at all, even when using test campaigns. I can only see IronSource ads

Comment: You are aware that Unity bought IronSource, right? [Link](https://www.businesswire.com/news/home/20221107005419/en/Unity-Completes-Merger-with-ironSource)

Comment: @tomerpacific yeah yeah What are you trying to convey?